# How to reduce the number async pipe subscriptions on template

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, async-pipe

I have this component [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypap5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html)

Template:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>dashboard-app</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Class:

```
export class NavigationComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

I want to reduce the number of subscriptions on the page.

I try to wrap the content in to `ng-container`, but that didn't work.

First of all I've got an error in template  in `[opened]="isHandset === false"`, second of all `ng-container` brake the view, so even if I leave as it is `[opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"` nothing was displayed

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isHandset$ | async as isHadset">
      <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
           [attr.role]="isHadset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
           [mode]="isHadset ? 'over' : 'side'"
           [opened]="isHadset === false"> //got an error here saying this condition is always false because isHadset is always 'true'
    ...
           *ngIf="isHadset"
    ...
    
    
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    <ng-container>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Any ideas how to fix all two issues I've described above ?

Comment: I checked your stackblitz, I susbscribe it and it works. I think for your case subscribe  & unsubscribe  manually would be better.
Check this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yn3y4?file=src/app/navigation/navigation.component.html

if you want to stick with async pipe, then friendly ignore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `*ngIf` with a `boolean` emission is not ideal since it won't render the element if the value is `false`. However I see that initially your emission is an object. And since objects are truthy, you could ignore the mapping to boolean and use it directly with the `*ngIf`.

I'd also recommend to wrap the entire container in the `<ng-container>` to preserve the DOM.

Try the following

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
...

export class NavigationComponent {
  isHandset$: Observable<BreakpointState>;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.isHandset$ = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async) as result">
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav 
      #drawer 
      class="sidenav" 
      fixedInViewport 
      [attr.role]="(result.matches) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(result.matches) ? 'over' : 'side'" 
      [opened]="!result.matches"
    >
      <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button
          type="button"
          aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
          mat-icon-button
          (click)="drawer.toggle()"
          *ngIf="result.matches"
        >
          <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>dashboard-app</span>
      </mat-toolbar>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lat4e3?file=src/app/navigation/navigation.component.html)